# Statistical tests for count data with many zeros

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, zero-inflation

I have to compare three groups (each group is a customer to a subscription box company).

Group A received treatment A.
Group B received treatment B.
Group C received no treatment.

We count the total number of boxes sold in each group (i.e. we are modelling count data)

I want to compare the mean number of boxes in group A and B vs the control (to see if the uplift is greater)

For this data ~2% of Group A got a box, ~2.1% of Group B got a box, and ~1.1% of Group C got a box.

What tests could we run to compare the means or the difference in uplift vs control for Group A and Group B?

I don't think a t-test or a Mann-Whitney test is appropriate here (though I am willing to be proven wrong!)

Comment: Run a zero inflated negative binomial model using group c as the reference.

Comment: Why isn't the outcome binary here if the data is at user level? Can users purchase more than one subscription box?

Comment: Why do you think this is zero inflated data as opposed to just data with zeroes in it?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov users can buy a box a week, and we look at how many boxes they bought in a 20-week window. The outcome would be binary if it was just conversions after 20 weeks.

Comment: @jbowman I'm not sure of the distinction, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DemetriPananos I don't know how to do that!

Comment: @jbowman it's suppose it's because we have two types of customers: those who will not buy a box regardless of the treatment, and those who will buy a box depending on the treatment.

Comment: Sure, but if you're modeling probabilities, there's no zero inflation - in the first case, the probability is very low that they will buy a box, in the second case, the probability is higher depending upon the treatment.   "Zero inflated" means, essentially, "too many zeroes relative to what we expect", e.g., if I have a Poisson with mean 1 I expect to observe a certain fraction of the data equalling zero, say 37%, but if some of those non-zero values are converted to zero by another process, I have an inflated probability of seeing zeros, hence a zero-inflated Poisson.

Comment: @jbowman We're not modelling probabilities - we're modelling the box count at 20 weeks.

Comment: If you are trying to build a zero-inflation model, you are modeling probabilities, specifically, the probability of a zero vs. a nonzero.  It's not at all clear to me that you need such a model.  The choice between a zero-inflation model and a non-zero-inflation model is made on the basis of whether the probability of seeing a zero is "too high" given the mathematical assumptions about the distribution of the data.  I am just not seeing any reason to make such an assumption from the problem description, or really make any distributional assumptions at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are to gather "uplift" is basically number of boxes. If you want to compare the *mean* number of boxes you should use an ANOVA. If the sample size is reasonably large, the sampling distribution of the mean is approximately normally distributed.

Models for count data can be used as well, given that the outcome is count. Poisson regression is the most common. Having many 0s does not mean the data are not Poisson, the rate could just be low. Quasipoisson and negative binomial models both just scale the variance so that the mean is merely proportional to the variance, in all cases the effect is interpreted as a relative rate of number of boxes.

A rank based test will tell you nothing about the mean. Rank tests in general are not a panacea for violations of modeling assumptions (which is separate from "having lots of zeroes"). Inferring differences in mean does not require that an exact parametric model is specified, rather using robust or asymptotic statistics will give you valid inference about mean differences.